# Im getting error when use google map javascript api to load map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Unable to load google maps correctly on this page  please need help: I use Maps Javascript API

[image]

Comment: [How do I ask a good question? - Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error commes up when you don't have a billing account on your project or you exceeded the daily limit.

[Google Maps API Usage and Billing](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage-and-billing) sais that:

> As of July 16, 2018, to continue to use the Google Maps Platform APIs,
>   you must enable billing on each of your projects. If you choose not to
>   add a billing account, your maps will be degraded, or other Maps API
>   requests will return an error.

Possible solutions:

- Use an alternative:

  - [Bing Maps API v8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428643.aspx)
  - [Here maps](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/quick-start.html)
- [Use a staticmap](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/intro)
- [Pay for Google maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage-and-billing#important-enable-billing)